# Multiple doneCallbacks in Deferred then

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

The documentation for [deferred.then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) states that doneCallbacks is `A function, or array of functions, called when the Deferred is resolved.`

When I write either     `.then(new Array(getData2, showDiv))` or     `.then([getData2, showDiv])`
none of them are called.

**What is the correct syntax?**

### Update

Should the syntax for array be `.then(new Array(getData2(), showDiv()))` or     `.then([getData2(), showDiv()])` with parenthesis?

See http://jsfiddle.net/JSw5y/894/

Comment: Are you sure your deferred gets resolved or rejected? Have you tried `done()` and `fail()`?

Comment: Most likely the deferred remains in the "pending" state (i.e. you have a logic error) because this syntax certainly works. Try this in the console: `$.Deferred().resolve().then([function() { console.log("foo"); }, function() { console.log("bar"); }]);`

Comment: @CarlR: That fiddle has several issues (including stuff executing on the spot instead of being set as a callback). Here's a [fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/JSw5y/896/). Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: @Jon Your version works. What did I do wrong in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/JSw5y/893/

Comment: @CarlR: The AJAX requests are failing so their promises never get fulfilled and the handlers are never called (they are *success* handlers). If you change `.then` to `.always` you will find that they are called correctly.

Comment: @Jon I'm afraid it's not that easy, because they are not failing. The log statements are put out correctly and the network tab shows http status 200. /echo/html is built into jsFiddle.

Comment: @CarlR: You are right (thanks for the tip). At first sight seems to be some kind of bug in jQuery: 1.8 will not work correctly using `.then`, although it will work with `.done` (wtf?). 1.7 will work correctly with both. Will investigate more later.

Answer (score -1):

This <strike>seems to be</strike> might be a bug in jQuery.

A simple workaround;

```
var CallbackHandler = (function () {
    var callbacks = [];

    return {
        'add': function (fn) {
            callbacks.push(fn);
            return this;
        },
        'executor': function () {
            var calledBy = this;
            $.each(callbacks, function () {
                this.call(calledBy);
            });
        }
    };

})();

CallbackHandler
    .add(function () {
        // first callback
    })
    .add(function () {
        // second callback
    });

// Called as:
$.when({a: 1})
 .then(CallbackHandler.executor);
```

Comment: A bug in jQuery? *Simple* workaround? Did you try something like `$.Deferred().resolve().then([function() { console.log("foo"); }, function() { console.log("bar"); }]);` to see that it works just fine?

Comment: @Jon - Of course I tried it (http://jsfiddle.net/gnu7R/) -- and yes, this is a *simple* workaround

Comment: Did you try the snippet above? There is absolutely no reason for all this.

Comment: @Jon - Did *YOU* try *my* fiddle? The $.get() method returns a Deferred jqHXR object -- and still the multiple callbacks doesn't get called.

Comment: I did. The first argument to [`.then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) is an array of callbacks that will be invoked when the deferred completes *successfully*. Your fiddle uses a deferred which *fails*. *Of course* the callbacks are not executed. The example with the workaround uses a deferred which resolves. If you had bothered trying on jsfiddle with `$.when` instead of `$.get` it would have worked fine.

Comment: @Jon - No, they do not fail. Open up Firebug or Chrome Inspector and look for yourself! The returned Deferred object from $.get() can not handle multiple callbacks.